# Custom Role in Azure to allow access to Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-rbac, azure-role-environment

I would like to give some users access to the analytics in PowerPlatform but feel that the Power Platform Administrator role gives too much access.
Is it possible to create a custom role that only provides read access?

I have created a custom role, attached it to the default subscription with all the permissions that Get-AZProviderOperation "Microsoft.PowerPlatform/*" returns but the assigned user still doesn't see the analytics tab.

Any pointers?
Thansk

Answer (score 0):

I think You've done the right thing creating a custom role, but make sure you've got all the neededd  permissions included. Think beyond just Microsoft.PowerPlatform/* and check operations specific to analytics.

Also, double-check if your users have the lowdown on data sources – permissions on connectors and data are key. Scope matters to0o; where you assign the role could be the game-changer.

finally keep an eye on the role hierarchy and any licensing quirks. Sometimes, it takes a bit for role changes to kick in.